# Trying to Find numbers that have 4 factors with Java Program but Output is Wrong

Tags: java, variables, input, output

I am trying to make a Java program that lets the user know if their number is a RSA number (or has 4 factors). This program keeps showing me the wrong output. For example, when the range is 11-15, instead of outputting 2, it outputs 0. Please advise.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
        int minimum = in.nextInt();    
        int maximum = in.nextInt();    
    
        int numOfFactors = 2;
        
        int numRSA = 0;
    
        int number = minimum;
    
        while (number>= minimum && number <= maximum){ 
            // condition for nonprime number
            for (int i = 2; i <= number/2; ++i) {
                if (number % i == 0 && number>=minimum && number<maximum) {
                    numOfFactors = numOfFactors + 1;
                }
            }
            if (numOfFactors == 4){
                numRSA = numRSA + 1;
            }
            number= number + 1;
        }
            
        System.out.println("The number of RSA numbers between " +minimum + " and " +maximum+ " is " +numRSA);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set numOfFactors back to 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work

Comment: Did you set it back to zero at the top of the loop?

Comment: Like I changed it from 2 to 0

Comment: So yes from my understanding, at the top of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `numOfFactors` within the while loop:

```java
while (number <= maximum){ 
    int numOfFactors =2;
    // condition for nonprime number
    for (int i = 2; i <= number/2; ++i) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            numOfFactors++;
        }
    }
    if (numOfFactors == 4){
        numRSA++;
    }
    number++;
}
```

You need to reset it for every number, then only the variable would have the number of factors for that particular number. In the current code, it stores the sum of factors till that number, which is causing the issue. (ex : after `12` the number of factors would be `6` which is not reset)

Comment: Thanks! Did that, and it worked for ranges 10 to 12 but not for another example like 11 to 15. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I totally see what you mean by resetting it! It's just that for ranges like 11-15, it shows '1' rsa num instead of 2

Comment: @Henry I have updated. `number>=minimum && number<maximum` this condition need not be used. The first condition would always evaluate to `true` and the second condition would skip the last number. For `11-15`, numbers with 4 factors are 14 and 15. So these conditions would skip `15` hance the output becomes `1` instead of `2`. I have updated the answer

Comment: @Henry no need for `number>=minimum` in the `while` loop. `number` is already initialized to `minimum` and it is not decremented in any part of the code. So `number>=minimum` would always be `true`. so that condition could be avoided from the while loop as well